# I would like to diplay the output(Mickey) in a wordpress page, instead of php page

Tags: wordpress

The following code is in a wordpress page.

```
<form action="action_page.php" method="post">
    Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="Mickey">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

action_page.php

```
<?php $name=$_POST['name']; echo $name;?>
```

I would like to diplay the output(Mickey) in a wordpress page, instead of php page. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it via AJAX, see the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_%28action%29)

Add this to functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_add_foobar', 'prefix_ajax_add_foobar' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_add_foobar', 'prefix_ajax_add_foobar' );

function prefix_ajax_add_foobar() {
    // Handle request then generate response using WP_Ajax_Response

    // In a real world scenario, apply all the validation, 
    // sanitization and black magic to POSTed variables before using them

    $name=$_POST['name']; 
    echo $name;
}
```

Now the following could go in footer.php inside of `<script>` tags or in a separate JS file.

```
jQuery.post(
    ajaxurl, 
    {
        'action': 'add_foobar',
        'data':   jQuery("form").sanitize() 
    }, 
    function(response){
        alert('The server responded: ' + response);            
    }
);
```

All things being equal you should see an alert with the value that was posted.